# how to fetch limited record on ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, pagination

I have 10,000 records in my database. I have used AJAX to fetch records. I am getting 10,000 records in JSON, but I want it to fetch the first 100 records then on next request another 100 and so on.

I have applied slice method but it is not working for condition type. I want to apply paging but I am not getting like how to apply paging on it.

```
$().ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:66252/Home/Getoptions", 
    success: function(result) { 
      //result has 10000 records 
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You need to do the paging on the server. The JS is irrelevant to the problem. Also note that `$().ready` is not a valid way of attaching a document.ready event handler. Use `$(document).ready(fn)` or `$(fn)`

Comment: get only 100 from your database. Implement pagination and fetch records on the basis of page.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan now this is valid form it is provided under Jquery offical documentation

Comment: That's not the case: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: See also: https://api.jquery.com/ready/ `As of jQuery 3.0, only the first syntax is recommended; the other syntaxes still work but are deprecated.`

Comment: Try this link it might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44412210/mvc-5-pagination-using-view-model/44416112#44416112

Comment: @sandeepgupta can you provide a link to the "jquery official documentation" for this please?

Comment: Check my answer bellow. Just copy and paste my code, it will work properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did,

**First time load:**

```
var pageSize = 100; // See, this is my default page size. You can change it.
$.ajax({
url: "http://localhost:66252/Home/Getoptions", 
data:{ skip: 0, take:100 },
success: function(result) { 
  var total = result.length;
  if (total > pageSize) {  // pageSize is 100, we declared on top
     var pageTotal = Math.ceil(total / pageSize);
     var j;
     for (var i = 0; i < pageTotal; i++) 
     {
       j = i + 1;
       //Here I'm creating li for all the pages. You can create any number of li then create a button called Next. Pass the value in Next button.
       var pages = '<li class="_li"><a id="page_' + j + '" class="pageNumber" style="margin-left:0px;" href="javascript:;">' + (i + 1) + '</a></li>';
       $('#_ul').append(pages); //This is my id of Ul from HTML
     }
   }
 });
```

**On Page Number click:**

```
$(document).on("click", ".pageNumber", function () {        
    var value = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
    var skip = value == 1 ? 0 : (value * pageSize) - pageSize;
    //Then call once again your ajax method here by passing skip value
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:66252/Home/Getoptions", 
      data:{ skip: skip, take:100 },
      success: function(result) { 
      var total = result.length;
      if (total > pageSize) {
        var pageTotal = Math.ceil(total / pageSize);
        var j;
        for (var i = 0; i < pageTotal; i++) 
        {
          j = i + 1;
          //Here I'm creating li for all the pages. You can create any number of li then create a button called Next. Pass the value in Next button.
          var pages = '<li class="_li"><a id="page_' + j + '" 
                       class="pageNumber" style="margin-left:0px;" 
                       href="javascript:;">' + (i + 1) + '</a></li>';
          $('#_ul').append(pages); //This is my id of Ul from HTML
        }
      }
    });
   });
```

Then in your `Action Method`, you can retrive the value of **query string**, for example,

```
string _skip = Request.QueryString["skip"];
string _take = Request.QueryString["take"];
```

Then You can add **Skip** and **Take** method in your `Linq` or `Entity Framework` query, for example,

```
var result = 
   myContext.GetData.Skip(int.Parse(_skip)).Take(int.Parse(_take)).ToList();
return json(result,jsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
```

**Note:** Please change the CSS or HTML accordingly as your requirement. For example, BG color of your Ul, or clicked Li color, or enable disable li etc etc.

Hope it helps :)